# how to select result from main query into subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, select, subquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to select count from main query into subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14357379/how-to-select-count-from-main-query-into-subquery)

I want to get the number of records that are selected in the main query into a subquery

Query that i am currently trying to execute is:

```
SELECT
    cat_id,
    category_name,
    seo_name,
    (
        SELECT count(category_name)
        FROM ccs_coupons
        WHERE website_name LIKE category_name
           OR description LIKE category_name
           OR url_desc LIKE category_name
    )  AnyAlias 
FROM  `ccs_coupons`
WHERE  category_name like 'a%'
GROUP BY category_name
ORDER BY category_name ASC
LIMIT $page,$config
```

Comment: why are you posting the exact same question you just asked 30 minutes ago?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    cat_id,
    category_name,
    seo_name,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(category_name)
        FROM ccs_coupons c2 
        WHERE c2.category_name LIKE CONCAT('%', c1.category_name, '%')
           OR c2.website_name LIKE CONCAT('%', c1.category_name, '%')
           OR c2.description LIKE CONCAT('%', c1.category_name, '%')
           OR c2.url_desc LIKE CONCAT('%', c1.category_name, '%')
    )  AnyAlias 
FROM  `ccs_coupons` c1 
WHERE  category_name LIKE 'a%'
GROUP BY category_name
ORDER BY category_name ASC
LIMIT $page,$config
```

Comment: Hi saharsh thanks for your reply but one thing more could LIKE %c1.category_name% in the subquery be used or if not how could the LIKE %% be used

Comment: This really worked. But it is taking really a long time

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
SELECT 
  a.cat_id
  ,a.category_name
  ,a.seo_name
  ,count(b.cat_id) as count
FROM 
  ccs_coupons as a
  INNER JOIN ccs_coupons as b
  ON  website_name = category_name
         OR description = category_name
         OR url_desc = category_name
WHERE 
  category_name like 'a%' 
GROUP BY 
  a.cat_id
  ,a.category_name
  ,a.seo_name 
ORDER BY 
  category_name ASC 
LIMIT 
  $page,$config
```

though i am not 100% sure what you are trying to do.. you may need to do some kind of unique constraint before doing the count